# How to scrape a webpage

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

I have been using scrapy for MichaelKors.com. Uptil now I have used SKUs from window.initial_state to get all the attributes and relevant information. However, there are certain webpages that I am unable to scrape, such as:
https://www.michaelkors.com/zip-hoodie-embellished-skirt-manhattan-crossbody-goldie-moto-boot/_/L-MSTR101179
It doesn't have SKUs so I tried getting it directly like this:

```
desc = response.xpath('//p[@class="look-description-desktop hide-on-mobile"]/text()').getall()
```

However, it is returning nothing.
What other attributes or aspect do you look into if you want to scrape specific information? I am a newbie so I'm quite unclear of where to go from here.

Comment: Please post your code and describe what you tried until now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath you wrote in your question gives you the description (at least when you render the page). To check how scrapy sees the webpage, you can do this in command line:

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.michaelkors.com/zip-hoodie-embellished-skirt-manhattan-crossbody-goldie-moto-boot/_/L-MSTR101179'

view(response)
```

You'll see there that you can find the description as follows:

```
response.xpath('//*[@property="og:description"]/@content').extract_first()
```

Comment: I realise its going off topic but what about getting the product's images that are displayed on the site. How do I get them?

Comment: Try to open the html-page with view(response) and check where you find back the image-urls, and then write an xpath-expression to get them.